# How to pass decimal value to Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following Action methods

```
public ViewResult Index()
public ActionResult Edit(decimal id)
```

When user clicks on Edit link, I want to invoke the `Edit` Action. Following is the sample code snippet

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ItemID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ItemID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id= item.ItemID})
</td>
```

The URL it redirects to is `http://MyServer/Orders/Details/0.020`

With this URL my action method does not invoke. If I manually edit the URL to remove "." then my method gets call.

My question is what is the right way to pass the decimal value to invoke the Action method?

Comment: Generally an ID would be an int or a GUID, it's unusual for it to be a decimal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do that is to pass it using query string:

```
http://MyServer/Orders/Details?id=0.20
```

How did you define your routes? Remove the id from the route and ActionLink will add it as query string.

Comment: Thanks Mark following is my route info  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Orders", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Remove the {id} and id = UrlParameter.Optional

Answer (score 2):

Try with custom [Decimal Model Binder](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/), a nice article by Phil Haack

abastract -

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your site's web.config within the system.webServer / handlers element

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
     path="*"
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write type in View. Ive used that for any type and it works excelent.

```
id=(decimal) item.ItemID
```