# Passing two decimal values to ASP .NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

I have a ASP .NET MVC controller that receive two decimal parameters:

```
[HttpGet, Route("stores/{latitude}/{longitude}")]
public void GetStores(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
{
    ...
}
```

This controller not working (404 error) when I invoke this url:

http://localhost:16959/store/stores/40.5479397/-3.6116505

But... if I modify my controller, and I add "/" in route string, I can invoke this url correctly (Postman):

```
[HttpGet, Route("stores/{latitude}/{longitude}/")]
public void GetStores(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
{
    ...
}
```

http://localhost:16959/store/stores/40.5479397/-3.6116505/

The problem now, is **Swagger** not recognize this slash "/" and never found controller.

My question is... What's the better way to solve this problem? Pass values in the body request? Add slash in the second parameter?

Comment: the dot (.) in the decimal is making the framework think it is a file extension for a file it can find. hence the 404 not found error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass decimal value to Action method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799263/how-to-pass-decimal-value-to-action-method)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the values in the query string? E.g

http://localhost:16959/store/stores?latitude=40.5479397&longitude=-3.6116505

Comment: Thanks it worked. It was not working when i tried passing decimal value without query string pattern

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Route("stores/{latitude}/{longitude}/") or modify URL template.
Just use `<input>` with name and then submit as URL Query string

```
<input Name="Latt" Type="Text" placeholder="Lattitude">
<input Name="Lang" Type="Text" placeholder="LAngitude">
<input  Type="Submit" >
```

use the above code in the begin form

If there is any problem in the controller input specification use like below

```
Public ActionResult Login (String Latt,String Long)
{
  decimal latt = (decimal)Latt;
  decimal long = (decimal)Long;
  (put your code here)

  }
```